# CSS Triangle shape sections with background image

Tags: html, css

I need to create a layout like this:

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3by9L.png)

As you can see, I need Triangle shapes on each section and set a background image

I tried with clip-path and I have managed to make the shapes but I have not been able to unite the separation that this generates, the first code is implemented with clip-path (I think maybe with css-grid and grid-areas maybe work but I not tried jet)

```css
    main {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      position: relative;
    }

    .service {
      height: 100vh;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }

    .service-1 {
      background-color: blue;
      clip-path: polygon(0 34%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 65%);
      top: 5px;
      left: 5px;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    .service-2 {
      background-color: pink;
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 34%, 100% 65%, 0 100%);
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 5px;
      bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .service-3 {
      background-color: yellow;
      clip-path: polygon(0 34%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 65%);
      top: 5px;
      left: 5px;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<main>
      <div class="service service-1">
        <h2>Service 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="service service-2">
        <h2>Service 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="service service-3">
        <h2>Service 3</h2>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Also, I tried with SVG but is the same result

```css
    main {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      position: relative;
    }

    .service {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .service-1 {
      background-color: blue;
      position: relative;
    }

    .service-1 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
    }

    .service-1 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 150px;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .service-1 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189 .shape-fill {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .service-1 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .service-1 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 150px;
    }

    .service-1 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504 .shape-fill {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .service-2 {
      background-color: pink;
      position: relative;
    }

    .service-2 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638774 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
    }

    .service-2 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638774 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 150px;
    }

    .service-2 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638774 .shape-fill {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .service-2 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638661 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .service-2 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638661 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 150px;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .service-2 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638661 .shape-fill {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }
    .service-3 {
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative;
    }

    .service-3 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
    }

    .service-3 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 150px;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .service-3 .custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189 .shape-fill {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .service-3 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    .service-3 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504 svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
      height: 150px;
    }

    .service-3 .custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504 .shape-fill {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<main>
      <div class="service service-1">
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189">
          <svg
            data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
          >
            <path
              d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z"
              class="shape-fill"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <h2>Service 1</h2>
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504">
          <svg
            data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
          >
            <path
              d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z"
              class="shape-fill"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="service service-2">
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-top-1624638774">
          <svg
            data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
          >
            <path
              d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z"
              class="shape-fill"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <h2>Service 2</h2>
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638661">
          <svg
            data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
          >
            <path
              d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z"
              class="shape-fill"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="service service-3">
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-top-1624638189">
          <svg
            data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
          >
            <path
              d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z"
              class="shape-fill"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <h2>Service 3</h2>
        <div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1624638504">
          <svg
            data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 1200 120"
            preserveAspectRatio="none"
          >
            <path
              d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z"
              class="shape-fill"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```